# Computer Randomly Restarts no BSOD or error (Custom PC Build)

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu, motherboard, crash

So I have a rather weird error, I just finished building a desktop made from custom picked parts (listed below). The installation process and everything went fine but when I started to install programs and actually use the desktop it randomly crashes and restarts.

**The issue:** Both my monitors will lose connection to the desktop at the exact same time, BUT all the LED lights (a lot of them) in the case don't even flicker. The fans (6 of them don't change or make any noise difference). After the monitors disconnected for about 10-15seconds the entire system will restart and boot into Windows 10 again (sometimes it will crash as soon as it starts and do a loop for a few times).

In the event the loop continues I have to turn off the switch to the PSU on the back and then flip it on to get it to start without crashing.

*The main part I have a hard time understanding, is that it is completely random. I can't figure out what triggers it. It could happen 10 seconds after I boot or it could go ~4 hours of gaming without an issue*

Things I think might be an issue:

- The first thing I thought was that it was a PSU issue, but I don't believe it is due to the fact that no lights, no fans, nothing at all seems to indicate that it is a loss of power to the rest of the system. Even if it is a surge, every other part of the computer that uses electricity would be affected? And certainly not enough to cause the system to reset?
- Overheating CPU. I thought this was the case but normally a CPU would need to reach around 70-80deg Celsius for that to happen. This crash often occurs when there is no load at all on the CPU, and it didn't happen while gaming and running 3D modeling software (CREO Parametic). I also installed a CPU temp monitor (CPU-Z) and it doesn't really spike to unstable temperatures. (I don't actually know the BOIS CPU temp cutoff, but if it does cutoff wouldn't the machine power down not do an actual restart?
- Maybe somehow the reset button is glitched? It doesn't seem that I am able to hold the power button down to kill all power to the board (have to manually flip the PSU) when it is in its weird restart loop state. And a reset seems like what is happening, it is reseting what is on my computer and causing a restart (maybe why I have the endless loop). I am pretty sure that I wired all the pins correctly according to the motherboard manual and the desktop case manual.
- Another thing I thought it could be was the RAM. When I first installed it, they were clocked in the BIOS at 2133Mhz (rated at 3200Mhz). So I changed the rating to the 3200Mhz value and started it (problem persists at random). I thought maybe I needed to up the voltage to the RAM so I changed the DRAM Voltage from 1.2V (Stock) to 1.35V. After that I played some video games for a ~4 hours with no issue, went to bed, turned it on the next day and then it instantly restarted. I also tried to look at the timings and stuff in the BIOS, I thought maybe that a setting was off but every single thing seemed accurate.

PC Parts:

- AMD Ryzen 2700X
- Stock AMD Wraith Cooler (Runs around 40deg idle)
- ASUS Prime X470-Pro
- Samsung 970 PRO 512GB NVMe
- Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB
- Thermaltake Toughpower DPS G RGB 750W Gold
- AMD Radeon R7 370 (Scrapped from old computer, no issues at all)
- Windows 10

Possible Solutions I might try?

- One possible solution if it is indeed the memory is to replace it with DDR3 sticks from my old build. If I can go a few days without any issues I think it would be safe to say that it is the memory?
- Run memtest on the ram sticks to determine if it is bad?
- Unplug and replug in all of the cables within the desktop
- Swap out my brand new 750PSU with my old EVGA 850W PSU

I would like to avoid having to disassemble the entire computer (I'm hoping it really is just a BIOS setting or bad memory). I also attached below a picture of the Windows 10 event viewer with the critical errors, each time this occurred it is labeled as a "Kernel-Power" issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I found a bunch of other posts with similar issues but none have a valid resolution (except one who returned everything and build a new computer). I do have a PSU (750W) which is strong enough to power the entire system, I have adequate air flow with the fans to ensure air is blowing in and out, and I am at a complete loss as I don't even know how to create it.

P.S. While writing this post every 30 sec I copied to a sticky note to save it just in case it crashed, so far it has been up for about ~ 38min without an issue (after it did its restart cycle on first power up).

EDIT: When looking at the supported memory for my Motherboard (https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/PRIME_X470-PRO/PRIME-X470-PRO-Memory-QVL-Ryzen-Radeon-Vega_Graphics.pdf?_ga=2.95208923.614721832.1547154730-1088761089.1547154730), I noticed that it didn't have the exact version of my RAM which is CMK16GX4M2B3200C16. Would that be an issue?

[Event Viewer Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Wt7.png)

Comment: Your hardware is only compatible with DDR4.  While I know you happened upon a solution (although what you did is not clear), it’s important to point out, your system only supports DDR4 and is incompatible with DDR3.

Comment: The RAM that I have on my build is Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 DRAM 3200MHz, which is stated to be DDR4. Is there part of my question that states it as DDR3? I knew ahead of time that it only supports DDR4 based on specifications of my hardware.

Comment: "Is there part of my question that states it as DDR3?" - You indicate on possible solution you thought about trying was to, **One possible solution, if it is indeed the memory, is to replace it with DDR3 sticks**, which obviously would not work.  I made my comment, to explain to everyone, that DDR3 is not compatible with DDR4 hardware.  Your question left me with the impression you were not aware that DDR3 was not compatible with your hardware.

Comment: Got it, my bad, I forgot that I posted that as a possible alternative. I was looking through my answer when reading your comment. Thank you for for clarifying that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to close out this question... so here goes.

I am not sure if I did find a solution for this but it was resolved, I ended up doing three things (at the same time) so I do not know for sure which one fixed it or a combination of the 3.

1. A lot of the only forums and SE pages I looked at referenced the Power Supply Unit. I kind of ruled that out early due to the fact I could run the PC at full CPU/GPU load without a single issue. I decided that I didn't want to risk it being an issue in the future (and while I could still return it) I just grabbed the exact same model from Fry's. Since it was a Modular PSU, all I did was swap out the connections going to the PSU, no need to take out the old wires and install new ones.
2. The second thing I decided to do was reseat all of the connections, I kind of figured this was redundant and not needed as all of my components properly powered on and were find under extreme stress. While reseating however, I found some things that led me to the third option.
3. When I did my installation they gave me this sort of bridge between the pins on the case and the motherboard (so that I didn't need to individual put each pin on it allowed you to put the pins on first then attach the whole thing as one unit to your board). When I went through the second time while reseating I noticed that they had two PWR LED +-. I figured, what the hell, and decided to switch it to the other one.

After finishing those three steps I put back together my machine and it worked perfectly, no issues since. I honestly think it was the third option that was causing it to fail, no clue how, but I'd rather not tempt fate and do further digging. Hopefully someone finds this useful!

Attached below is the diagram from the X470 PRO motherboard with the pinout that confused me. [Pinout for mboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeWWA.png)

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a problem with the motherboard - GPU compatibility.

Check your build here : https://www.userbenchmark.com/PCBuilder

Comment: What's at the link, did you check it with the listed hardware?

Comment: I'm with Xen2050, when I go to the link and I replicate my build it doesn't say anything about a compatibility issue? And so far my video games and triple monitors run flawlessly? No issues at all.

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes, I checked the compatibility of listed hardware.

Comment: @97WaterPolo Check the link : https://www.userbenchmark.com/PCBuilder/Custom/S86010-M475904.8791.498971.89530vsS0-M?tab=MBD

Comment: When you specify the specific model, R7 370,there are no listed compatibility issue? If that is the case, why am I able to game and have all my monitors work without any issue? The graphics seems to work fine, this was the thing that I least expected to be the issue?